# Nativescript fire event from webview

Tags: html, events, webview, nativescript

I have an HTML5 website that I want to convert to a Nativescript app. I'm planning on wrapping the website in a [Webview](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/web-view) but I wanted to know if there is a way to exchange information between the Webview and the Nativescript code so I can run a Nativescript function when certain pages appear in the Webview.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with the [Webview Interface Plugin.](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-webview-interface)